# convert integer column to date column yyyy sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, database, date, type-conversion, integer

I want to change data type of a column on a db in sqlserver 2019.
the data is stored in the column as integer and i want to convert it to date format yyyy.
the data stored could be 2016 OR 2017 etc.
How can I do that please ? THANK YOUU

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense. Dates consist of a day, month and year. 2017 isn't a date.

Comment: is there a way to stock only years ? because we will use only years to display charts later

Comment: If you want to store a date *range* you need 2 columns; the start date and end date.

Comment: i think there is an other way, thanks anyway

Comment: You think *what* is the other way..? The other way to what? You **cannot** store the `int` value `2017` in a `date` because it *isn't* a date... This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info)

Comment: here's the thing, i want to display a chart to know income by year  so i have a column where there is income and a column where there is the year, but when i display it it doesn't work correctly, power bi needs to know that its a date to display it correcty, do you see an idea?

Comment: Do what ***date*** is 2017? But *perhaps* what you should actually be asking about is the problem you're having in Power BI, not how to convert an `int` representing a year to a `date` (i.e. which would be X).

Comment: how do we concatenate 2 columns (year column and month column both int ) into one column which will be date format mmyyyy in sqlsever?

Comment: That's not a date either... *"Dates consist of a **day**, month and year."*

Comment: As pointed out, in SQL Server, you need a day, month, and year to use the `date` data type - there's no way around that. If you must use it, then store the first of each month of each year you're reporting on, e.g. `01/01/2020`, `01/01/2021`, `01/01/2022`. But I believe you can just use an `INT` column for your years in PowerBI and as Larnu mentioned, you should be asking for help on how to do that.

Comment: So when you want to run this specific report, just say `SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, datecolumn) FROM ...` without losing any information, changing the data, or using a different data type...

Comment: In order to convert the column's data-type, the values in it must be valid for the new data-type. If you have values like '2017', you won't be able to alter it. If the column is irrelevant, then create a new column with the Date data-type. And migrate the values, "aligning" the ones that need handling. Alternatively, you can take the same "aligning" logic and create a "Computed Column" which will have the "date" version of the "int" values you have. That way the existing column is untouched. You can also place that convert logic in the report query itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEFROMPARTS` to get the first day in every month

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(yearInt, monthInt, 1), OtherColumns
FROM YourTable;
```

Or for the first day in each year

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(yearInt, 1, 1), OtherColumns
FROM YourTable;
```

You can also group up by that value:

```sql
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(yearInt, 1, 1), OtherColumns
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 
  DATEFROMPARTS(yearInt, 1, 1);
```

---

Or to create a new column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTable
  ADD YourDateColumn date NOT NULL;
```

```sql
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourDateColumn = DATEFROMPARTS(yearInt, monthInt, 1);
```